# Get all Woocommerce categories in dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i've been working a day for this, im so stress, can you help me retrieve woocommerce all categories in dropdown menu? here i want to retrieve in dropdown menu

```
    $options[] = array(  
     "name" => "Featured section category",
        "desc" => "Select the category that you would like to have displayed in Featured list on your homepage.",
        "id" => $shortname."_story_category",
        "std" => "Uncategorized",
        "type" => "select",
        "options" => $woo_category);
```

how can i show all category in this var $woo_category, i use this code but its show wordpress categories not woocommerce

```
$woo_categories = array();
$woo_categories_obj = get_categories( 'hide_empty=0' );
foreach ($woo_categories_obj as $woo_cat) {
$woo_categories[$woo_cat->cat_ID] = $woo_cat->cat_name;}
$categories_tmp = array_unshift($woo_categories, "Select a category:" );
```

help me with this simple task,

Comment: can you plz tell me which theme you are using?

Answer (score 2):

This simple query can get all your woocommerce categories..

```
$args = array( 'type' => 'product', 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' ); 
$categories = get_categories( $args );
```

And for displaying..

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') ?>"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: hi thanks for helps, but i wanna show in dropdown menu, in my custom metabox, like this code $options[] = array(  
     "name" => "Featured section category",
        "desc" => "Select the category that you would like to have displayed in Featured list on your homepage.",
        "id" => $shortname."_story_category",
        "std" => "Uncategorized",
        "type" => "select",
        "options" => $woo_category);  only that will show dropdown with categories

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass taxonomy

```
$args=array(           
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
            );
$woo_categories_obj = get_categories($args);
```

Comment: so how do i use that? like this?  "type" => "select",
            "options" => $woo_categories_obj);